# Creating Java conversion table from Fahrenheit to Celsius

Tags: java, for-loop

I am new to this site and new to programming I just started a week a go. I've been tasked with making a conversion table from degrees Fahrenheit to Celsius. the table needs to start at 0 Celsius and stop at 100 degrees Celsius and go by increments of 5.

I am really trying to make it work but I can't seem to get the `for loop` working correctly. Can someone explain to me what I am doing wrong and how I can finish this program to work the way I need it?

```
public class Table 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        System.out.println("Conversion Table");
        final int TOTAL = 100;
        for (int c = 0; c <= TOTAL; c+=5)
        {
            System.out.println((c*9/5)+32 +"\t");
            {
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }
```

https://ideone.com/llmOER

Comment: Well, your code sample is missing a closing brace, which I assume is a copy/paste error. Aside from that, it looks like this code is supposed to print out the Farhenheit value of every 5 degrees C, which I think it does. What do you expect it to do, and what is it doing instead?

Comment: Could you describe what’s not right exactly?

Comment: @BriTheCyberGuy18 Can you provide what you expect the output of the program should be?

Comment: Well, it prints a list of numbers, which are temperatures in Fahrenheit.  Perhaps you should add a line to print the value of `c`, as well as printing the converted temperature on the same line.  You may want to use `System.out.print` instead of `System.out.println` for that line.

Comment: Ah. Reading the question again, I'm guessing the problem is just in what you're writing out. I'd suggest calculating the value outside the `println`, like this: `int f = (c * 9 / 5) + 32;`, which makes the printing clearer: `System.out.println(c + "\t" + f);`

Comment: @BriTheCyberGuy18 I am guessing that all your values are printout out 32 for the fahrenheit, that's because you don't case the value to be int, look at my Answer as it works quite nicely. EDIT oh I see you just aren't printing out the celsius value, still my answer is a nice way to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently you are only printing the values of the Fahrenheit to standard out. If the idea is that you want to print to standard out the table then you probably want to add the Celsius value as well.
Add something like

```
System.out.println(c +  "\t" + ((c*9/5)+32) +"\t");
```

to your output and you'll be sweet.

Comment: There's a chance you are right, but it's a far stretch without extra input from the asker.

If the asker expects this output from this code, then more explanation as to what the original was outputting and why would be more helpful to them.

Comment: sorry I didn't add in any extra information about the error I was having... like I said I'm new to programming and didn't even think about giving more information. but this added code and an extra brace solved my problem. Thank you!!!!

Comment: No worries. Thanks @RyanTheLeach for the comment too. I'm pretty new to this as well so still finding my feet. Next time I will try to add more explanation as to what my code is doing.

Answer (score 0):

1-You have one less closing brace.
2-For making conversion table you have to show both Fahrenheit and Celsius value. Code for this would be.

```
public class A 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        System.out.println("Conversion Table");
        final int TOTAL = 100;
    System.out.println("Fahrenheit"+"\t Celsius");
        for (int c = 0; c <= TOTAL; c+=5)
        {
            System.out.println((c*9/5)+32 +"\t \t" + c);
            {
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
     }
}
```